# How do i find the email address used as an icloud ID for an icloud locked phone?

Tags: ios, icloud, email, apple-id

My aunty bought an iPhone 5s from a second phone dealer for my kid sister as a gift but the phone appears to be icloud locked but not in lost mode. Since it's not in lost mode, I'm supposing the phone isn't stolen and would like to contact the previous user to help remove the phone from his icloud account. How will i get the email address used for the icloud account? Can anyone help us out?

Answer (score 3):

Take it back to the dealer. See if they have the contact details. If not, get your money back, they should have checked before even buying it from the previous owner.

The entire email address is never exposed, so you won't be able to access it.

Even if not stolen, if the original owner doesn't [remove it from their iCloud account](https://support.apple.com/en-qa/HT201351), there's no way to bypass the Activation Lock.